# fly execute on localhost fails

Tags: macos, concourse

I have a simple task that I want to execute on my local concourse instance:

**build-frontend.yml**

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: node
    tag: 'latest'

inputs:
- name: client-devops

run:
  path: client-devops/scripts/test
```

the task is executed:

```
client-devops daka$ fly -t frontend execute --config build-frontend.yml
executing build 1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
gzip: invalid magic
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
exit status 2
```

The target is available:

```
client-devops daka$ fly targets
name          url                         expiry                       
frontend      http://127.0.0.1:8080       Fri, 11 Nov 2016 09:13:55 UTC
```

Why does it say can't connect to localhost, I can connect to the UI from my browser?

Comment: Interesting - I'd suggest using tools like `tcpdump` and `netcat` to work out what's going on with connections to `localhost:8080`.

Is it possible Concourse has bound to a different interface?

Comment: It was probably an inconsistency in the YAML file, not very clear error message though

Comment: Ah, did you get it fixed then?

Comment: Yes, rewrote my pipeline yml from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Your external URL cannot be configured as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` - it has to be reachable by other machines.